DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[cac:Party]'
DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[cac:Party]' contains unresolvable namespaces.

 const parser = new DOMParser();
            const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
            const partyNode = xmlDoc.evaluate('//*[cac:Party]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();

            const partyIdentification = partyNode.querySelector('cac\\:PartyIdentification cbc\\:ID').textContent;
            const partyName = partyNode.querySelector('cac\\:PartyName cbc\\:Name').textContent;
            const citySubdivisionName = partyNode.querySelector('cac\\:PhysicalLocation cac\\:Address cbc\\:CitySubdivisionName').textContent;
            

Fill json 
  const jsonData = {
                partyIdentification,
                partyName,
                physicalLocation: {
                    citySubdivisionName,
                    cityName,
                    countrySubentity,
                    identificationCode
                },
                electronicMail
            };


Your XPath includes namespace prefixes, so you need to pass a namespace resolver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate
